# SetKeyDelay for Mouse Wheel

Tags: autohotkey

I want to scroll a page 5 times, with a small delay after each scroll. But instead of this, the page is scrolled without delays. Why?

```
~+PgDn::
SetKeyDelay, 50
Send, {WheelUp 5}
Return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For mouse clicks, `SetMouseDelay` should be used, but apparently WheelUp and WheelDown don't count as clicks so it won't work for them.

Use a Sleep command and a Loop instead:

```
Loop, 5
{
    Send,  {WheelUp}
    Sleep, 50
}
```

Consider wrapping this into a function for convenience.